# Ruby types and singleton methods

Tags: ruby, rbs, steep

I'm seeing some unexpected behaviour setting up RBS types on an existing Ruby project.  A minimal example:

```rb
# lib/a.rb
class A
  def self.foo
    new
  end
end

class B < A
  def self.foo
    super
  end
end

puts A.foo.inspect
puts B.foo.inspect
```

Output

```
#<A:0x000055f7cfb03908>
#<B:0x000055f7cfb037f0>
```

Signature

```rb
# lib/a.rbs
class A
  def self.foo: () -> A
end

class B < A
  def self.foo: () -> B
end
```

but the steep type-checker gives me errors

```
lib/a.rb:8:11: [error] Cannot allow method body have type `::A` because declared as type `::B`
│   ::A <: ::B
│     ::Object <: ::B
│       ::BasicObject <: ::B
│
│ Diagnostic ID: Ruby::MethodBodyTypeMismatch
│
└   def self.foo
             ~~~
```

Is this an issue with steep or (more likely) my understanding of the Ruby typing syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this an issue with steep or (more likely) my understanding of the Ruby typing syntax?

I believe it is neither.

Your syntax is perfectly fine (otherwise steep would not even be able to parse the RBS file and give you a syntax error) and I also don't see any problem with steep here. The code you have is *genuinely* type-unsafe according to the types you have declared:

- `B::foo` is declared to return an instance of `B`
- `B::foo` returns `super`
- `super` is `A::foo`
- `A::foo` is declared to return an instance of `A`
- **ergo**, `B::foo` is declared to return an instance of `B` but it actually returns an instance of `A`.

Since `A` is not convertible to `B`, this is not type-safe.

Comment: So the type-signature of A.foo needs to be modified to list all types that it might return if called from a super (in which case it with return the new of the subclass, and so its type?), that seems, ..., to violate encapsulation?